# SvnPlot - Ignore directory/filetype in LOC statistics

Tags: svn

Is there any way to tell svnplot to ignore some directory paths in SVN or to ignore specific filetypes (i.e. .html).
I have tried to delete paths in sqlite DB without success.

svnplot - http://code.google.com/p/svnplot/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed reply, saw this question just now. I am SVNPlot developer.

There is no direct way to ignore the specific filetypes. You have to change sql queries to ignore the file types. The queries are in svnstats.py file.

I think its a good feature to have. Please add a feature request to svnplot issuebase. I will try to do something about it.